# Using install_github with different repo/package name

Tags: r, github, r-package

I've create an R package on the company's github site, with an address something like:

```
https://github.com/<Company_Name>/dstools.<package>.git
```

I've tried to install the package using `install_github("<Company_Name>/<package>")` but that doesn't work, presumably because the package folder is prefixed by "dstools." Is there a workaround for this, e.g. can I just paste the github URL in the `install_github` command and get that to work?

Comment: Did you try `install_github("<Company_Name>/dstools.<package>")`? You need to exactly match the repo name. The values there don't indicate what the actual package name will be. That's defined in the DESCRIPTION file of the package.

Comment: And if `.git` is part of the repository name then you need the fully-qualified `install_github("company_name/dstools,package.git")` -- as if you browsed to the directory because that is where GitHub has it.  As @MrFlick correctly points out, the _package_ name is determined _inside the repository_ via the `DESCRIPTION` file.

Comment: Thanks for the help! The company name needed to be capitalized and now it works! Strange, the company name is not capitalized in the URL. Adding .git does not work but it was worth a try. Thanks again for helping me out!